# JQuery selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy intentando hacer un un select que tiene options y me gustaria cuando la pagina este cargada selecionara el valor que esta guardado en un localstorage y hiciera el selected de la option.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   modality = localStorage.getItem("modality")
  jQuery('#modality-id option:selected').attr('modality');
})
```

Pero el option:selected no lo hace, me pueden ayudar? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

aca te dejo como hacerlo con jQuery, ya que `localStorage` esta bloqueado cree un imput para que veas como seleccionar un valor automaticamente :

```js
$("#localstorage").on("keyup", () => {
    $("#miselect").val($("#localstorage").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="localstorage" type="text" placeholder="introduce un numero de 1 a 9 ">

<select id="miselect">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option> 
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
</select>
```

en tu caso con `localStorage` tendria que ser asi :

```
//Javascript 
var select = document.getElementById("modality");
select.value = localStorage.getItem("modality");

//jQuery
$("#modality").val(localStorage.getItem("modality"));
```

para seleccionar un valor de un select, tenes que pasarle un valor, osea con `$("#id").val(..)` o `element.value = ....`

espero te sea de ayuda